# Using FilterInputStream to drop remainder of an InputStream

Tags: java, yaml, java-io

I plan to use Java to process Markdown text files that specify additional meta information like title, author, date of creation etc. at the beginning of the document in the YAML format. Here's an example:

```
---
title: An example document
author: Paul
created: 2013-05-19
---

The _body_ of this document is
written in **Markdown**.
```

For parsing the YAML data, I could use [snakeyaml](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/). As far as I can tell, you can load YAML documents from a `java.io.InputStream`, a `java.io.Reader` or a `String` through the methods `yaml.load()` and `yaml.loadAll()` (see [the SnakeYAML documentation](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Loading_YAML) and [API](http://snakeyamlrepo.appspot.com/releases/1.10/site/apidocs/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29)).

I don't want to use the version that reads from a `String`, since this will cause performance issues with large files. But working with the file as an `InputStream` fails, because the stream does not represent a valid YAML document. Only the first part of the stream represents the valid document.

So my question is: How can I use `java.io.FilterInputStream`/`java.io.FilterReader` or another approach to generate a stream, that stops after the second `---` so the overall stream is valid YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (Scala code):

```scala
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.charset.Charset

import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

/**
 * Reader for Metadata that is contained in the given `InputStream`.
 *
 * @constructor Create a new metadata reader with a given `Charset`.
 * @param in underlying input stream
 * @param charset encoding of the stream
 */
class MetadataReader(in: InputStream, charset: Charset)
    extends InputStreamReader(in, charset) {
  private val lookahead = Queue.empty[Int] // buffer for looking ahead
  private var afterNewline = true // indicates that the last char was a newline
  private var divider = 0 // number of divider characters in a row ('-')

  /**
   * Create new MetadataReader with the systems default `Charset`.
   *
   * @param in underlying input stream
   */
  def this(in: InputStream) = this(in, Charset.defaultCharset())

  /**
   * Read the next character.
   *
   * @return next character
   */
  override def read: Int =
    if (divider == 2) {
      -1
    } else if (!lookahead.isEmpty) {
      lookahead.dequeue
    } else {

      // read next character
      def readNext: Int =
        if (lookahead.length == 3) {
          divider += 1
          read
        } else {
          val c = super.read
          if (c == '-') {
            lookahead.enqueue(c)
            readNext
          } else {
            lookahead.enqueue(c)
            lookahead.dequeue
          }
        }

      readNext
    }

  /**
   * Read characters into a buffer character array.
   *
   * @param buf buffer array
   * @param off offset to start in the array
   * @param len number of characters to read
   * @return actually read characters
   */
  override def read(buf: Array[Char], off: Int, len: Int): Int = {
    var j = 0
    for (i <- 0 until len) {
      val c = read

      if (c == -1)
        return j

      if (i >= off) {
        buf(i) = c.toChar
        j += 1
      }
    }

    j
  }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```scala
val yaml = new Yaml
val mr = new MetadataReader(new FileInputStream(
  new File("src/test/resources/yaml-test.txt")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
println(yaml.load(mr))
mis.close()
```

Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add "..." (three dots) where you want the YAML parser should stop.

Comment: This is a neat solution, but I have to stop after `---` to be compatible with [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).